# From String to Attribute in Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use strings in place of :attribute. In the example below:

```
<%= f.label :column1 %>
```

Instead of this, I want to be able to do the same thing via a string like:

```
<%= f.label "column1" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

to_sym converts string to symbol